# regex street number separator

Tags: c#, regex, street-address

I have a address field that I want to separate in street name and house-number suffix, first part of address (street-name) is not a problem but the second part for the house-number suffix is a bit tricky. 

 In bold is the part that I want to select:

- 1st street **25**
- 1st street **25 a**
- 1st street **25b**
- 1st street **25-ab**

And this is the regex code that I use in c# to output only the house number suffix, but so far no luck selecting the bold parts:

```
{
  string sNum = AdField;
  string sRep = @"\s(\d[^\s]*[ A-Z]\w*)?(\d\w\s)\s?(.+)";
  string output = Regex.Match(sNum, sRep).Value;

  return output;
}
```

Comment: Does it always come after the second space?

Comment: No not always, some addresses are like "Address line line 25"

Comment: @H35am If the answer below works in all cases, please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

I think think you can do it with this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tTWcvW/1) 
the regex is

```
\d+(\s|-)?\w*$
```

Comment: My test method was also faulty, your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-z]+ ?([0-9]+ ?\-?[a-z]{0,2})
```

**[Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/1qiFwy/1)**

```
[a-z]+
```

catching the last part of the streetname

```
 ?
```

watch the space in front of the `?` means 1 or 0 spaces

```
[0-9]+
```

1 or more numbers

```
 ?
```

another optional space

```
\-?
```

optional dash (-)

```
[a-z]{0,2}
```

0 to 2 letters